# Access an attribute from another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm very new to Rails, so please bear with me. A user can have many mentors, a Mentor belongs to user

```
  class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :confirmable, :omniauthable

  validates :firstname, :lastname, presence: true
  has_many :mentors


class Mentor < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :photos
```

I would need to use user name within the Mentor show page. Could someone tell me what should I do? As I said before, I'm very new to Rails. So if someone could tell me step-by-step changes that I need to do, that would be extremely helpful.

Comment: https://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have defined `@mentor` in `MentorsController#show`:

```
"#{@mentor.user.firstname} #{@mentor.user.lastname}"
```

Comment: do you know how could I pull a mentor attribute to the related user show page? Thank you.